# Google apps script to re-execute function using trigger

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am new to javascript or google apps script. I am using this function to import data into MySQL database from a google spreadsheet. This sheet has over 16000 records and I would want to breakdown the import into smaller batches of 2000 records. In the function createGASTrigger() how would  I change my logic to grab first 2000 records from the spreadsheet in the first iteration and then the next 2000 records in second iteration and so on.

**Function 1**

```
var address = 'database_IP_address';
var rootPwd = 'root_password';
var user = 'user_name';
var userPwd = 'user_password';
var db = 'database_name';

var root = 'root';
var instanceUrl = 'jdbc:mysql://' + address;
var dbUrl = instanceUrl + '/' + db;

function myFunction() {   

  var stime = new Date();
  var col1;
  var col2;
  var col3;

  var dbconnection = Jdbc.getConnection(dbUrl, root, rootPwd);
  var statement = dbconnection.createStatement();
  var googlesheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('sheet1'); 
  var data = googlesheet.getDataRange().getValues();  

dbconnection.setAutoCommit(false)

for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
col1 = data[i][0];
col2 = data[i][1];
col3 = data[i][2];

var sql = "{call [dbo].[sp_googlesheetimport](?,?,?)}";
statement = dbconnection.prepareCall(sql);
statement.setString(1, col1);
statement.setString(2, col2);
statement.setString(3, col3);
statement.addBatch();
}

statement.executeBatch();
dbconnection.commit();
statement.close();
dbconnection.close();

  var etime = new Date();
  Logger.log('Exec time: ' + (etime.getTime() - stime.getTime()));
}
```

**Function 2**

```
function createGASTrigger() {
    var varUserPropertiesService = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
    var varUserTriggerId = varUserPropertiesService.getProperty("myFunction");
    var varUserTrigger = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();

    for (var i in varUserTrigger) {
      if (varUserTrigger[i].getUniqueId() == varUserTriggerId)
        try 
        {
          ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(varUserTrigger[i]);
        } 
        catch(e)
        {
          Utilities.sleep(30000);
          ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(varUserTrigger[i]);
        }
    }  

    myFunction();

    var userProperties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
    try 
    {
      var nextTrigger = ScriptApp.newTrigger("myFunction").timeBased().after(1 * 120 * 1000).create();
    } 
    catch(e)
    {
      Utilities.sleep(30000);
      var nextTrigger = ScriptApp.newTrigger("myFunction").timeBased().after(1 * 120 * 1000).create();
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tested this but I think this is a good starting point.

```
function myFunction() {   

  var stime = new Date();
  var col1;
  var col2;
  var col3;
  var dbconnection = Jdbc.getConnection(dbUrl, root, rootPwd);
  var statement = dbconnection.createStatement();
  var googlesheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('sheet1'); 
  var data = googlesheet.getDataRange().getValues(); 
  var itrows=1000;
  var complete=false;
  if(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('iteration'))
  {
     var iteration=Number(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('iteration') + 1); 
  }
  else
  {
    var iteration=Number(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('iteration', 1));
  }

  var max=itrows * iteration;
  var min=max - itrows + 1;
  if(max>data.length-1)
  {
    max=data.length-1;
    complete=true;
  }


  dbconnection.setAutoCommit(false)

  for (var i=min;i<=max;i++) 
  {
    col1 = data[i][0];
    col2 = data[i][1];
    col3 = data[i][2];
    var sql = "{call [dbo].[sp_googlesheetimport](?,?,?)}";
    statement = dbconnection.prepareCall(sql);
    statement.setString(1, col1);
    statement.setString(2, col2);
    statement.setString(3, col3);
    statement.addBatch();
  }

  statement.executeBatch();
  dbconnection.commit();
  statement.close();
  dbconnection.close();
  if(complete)
  {
    PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().deleteProperty('iteration');
  }
  var etime = new Date();
  Logger.log('Exec time: ' + (etime.getTime() - stime.getTime()));
}

function createGASTrigger() {
    var varUserPropertiesService = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
    var varUserTriggerId = varUserPropertiesService.getProperty("myFunction");
    var varUserTrigger = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();

    for (var i=0;i<varUserTrigger.length;i++)
    {
      if (varUserTrigger[i].getUniqueId() == varUserTriggerId)
      {
        ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(varUserTrigger[i]);
        break;
      }
    }  
    var userProperties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
    var nextTrigger = ScriptApp.newTrigger("myFunction").timeBased().after(1 * 120 * 1000).create();
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

Either store a page value in `PropertiesService.getScriptProperties()` or add a value to the spreadsheet for all rows as you add them